# Decrypt a Java string

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to make a program in java that's decrypting a text.

Example:

Input: ABKBFA

Output: ABBA

Rules:

> - Keep the first letter and the last letter
> - Jump over some letters dependence of alphabet (A-Z), The Alphabet has values  A=1 B=2 C=3... So if the word is "HZBKRYAFEAAAAJ" it will first keep the letter H, and because H=8, it will jump 8 steps and land on E. When it lands on E, the word is HE, but it is not finished. E=5, so 5 steps to jump and it lands on J, and the word will be "HEJ".

I have not come as far to know how to solve this problem. Right now it only saves the last and the first.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       String text = sc.nextLine();
       char[] alphabet = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
       char firstLetter = 0;
       char lastLetter = (char) (text.length()-1);

          System.out.println(text.charAt(firstLetter)+""+text.charAt(lastLetter));


}
```

Comment: Read about LOOPs (for; while; do while) then about concatenation of strings. You are missing a loop trough text.

Comment: are capital letters treated differently ??

Comment: Only uppercase letter

Comment: Are you only expecting uppercase letters as input?

Answer (score 0):

Just writing raw function which does it:

```
public static String decrypt(String text) {
        String returned = "";
        //Read first letter
        char c = text.charAt(0);
        returned+=c;
        //Skip value
        int skip = 0;

        if(Character.isLowerCase(c))
            skip = c - (int)'a' + 1;
        else
            skip = c -(int)('A') + 1;

        if(text.length() >= skip+2)
            returned +=  decrypt(text.substring(skip));
        else
            //Return the last character
            returned += String.valueOf(text.charAt(text.length()-1));

        return returned;
    }
```

Output:

```
ABBA
HEJ
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that is your homework (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), i wont post a complete answer, but some tips.

So you concatenate one character at a time

1. The character at the start of the string
2. The following character N positions after the previous character (if c is the char, c - 'a' + 1, as 'a' is 1).
3. Repeat #2 until you reach the end position (i >= s.length() - 1)
4. append the final character.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Decryptor{

    public HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Decryptor d = new Decryptor();
        d.setAlphabet();
        d.decrypt();
    }

    public void setAlphabet(){      
        int i = 1;
        for(char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z';alphabet++) {
            map.put(alphabet+"",i);
            i++;
        }
    }

    public void decrypt(){
        String text = "HZBKRYAFEAAAAJ";
        String answer = "";
        int pos = 0;
        while(true){
            answer += text.charAt(pos);
            pos = map.get("" + text.charAt(pos));
            if(pos >= text.length){
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only capital letters are inputted as data:

```
1. Append the first letter to the result
2. The jump point is calculated by taking the (current letter) - 'A' + 1
   'A' - 'A' + 1 = 1
   'B' - 'A' + 1 = 2
   etc...
3. Check if the current position plus the jump is less than the location of the last letter
   If true, append the letter at the jump point to the result and move to that point
   If false, you're done
4. Repeat 2 & 3 until 3 results false
5. Append the last letter to the result
```

Code sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scanner.nextLine();

    // Add the first letter
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(input.charAt(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length() - 2;) {
        // Find out how far to jump
        int jump = input.charAt(i) - 'A' + 1;

        // Check if the jump from the current position is before the last letter
        if (i + jump < input.length() - 1) {
            // Append the letter at the jump point
            sb.append(input.charAt(i + jump));

            // Move to the jump point
            i += jump;
        } else {
            // We're done
            break;
        }
    }

    // Add the last letter
    sb.append(input.charAt(input.length() - 1));

    // Display result
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Results:

```
ABKBFA => ABBA
HZBKRYAFEAAAAJ => HEJ
AZZZ => AZZ
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just for Fun :)**

```
public class decrypt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Error! Exiting...");
            System.out.println("Usage: java decrypt ENCRYPTED_WORD");
            System.out.println("       ENCRYPTED_WORD not found !!");
        } else {
            //Convert the Encrypted text to upper case, in case it was lower case
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(args[0]);
            for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
                char c = sb.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                    sb.setCharAt(i, Character.toUpperCase(c));
                }
            }
            boolean mError = false;
            int mCounter = 0;
            StringBuilder Rezult = new StringBuilder("");
            Rezult.append(sb.charAt(mCounter));
            while (mCounter < sb.length()-1) {
                try {
                    mCounter += sb.charAt(mCounter) - 'A' + 1;
                    Rezult.append(sb.charAt(mCounter));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    mError = true;
                }
            }
            if (mError) {
                System.out.println("Your input is incorrect!! Cannot Decrypt");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Decrypted Code is: " + Rezult);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compile as:

```
javac decrypt.java
```

Run as:

```
java decrypt abkbfa
```

Examples:

```
>>java decrypt
Error! Exiting...
Usage: java decrypt ENCRYPTED_WORD
       ENCRYPTED_WORD not found !!

>>java decrypt ams
Your input is incorrect!! Cannot Decrypt

>>java decrypt abkbfad
Decrypted Code is: ABBAD

>>java decrypt HZBKRYAFEAAAAJ
Decrypted Code is: HEJ
```